# Anaconda navigotor and its applications wont work

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, anaconda

Anaconda navigator along and its enclosed applications stopped working when **qtpy4** package was inserted manually, clicking their .exe icons wont raise any errors as nothing happens.

> But upon manual launch of

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\anaconda-navigator.exe
```

or

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\spyder.exe
```

> Raised the attached error

Qtpy error

[image]

***It is worth mentioning jupyter-notebook.exe launched from**

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe
```

**Worked fine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple **reinstall** sufficed, turns out the problem was in pipeline for `pyqt` as it broke conflicting qt5 binding.

> P.s Happened when I accidentally install qt4 package over already
>   existing qt5 package in anaconda.